# Include Gruntfile and run a task in an another file

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I have an app using Grunt, that I launch in my terminal, and I want to run a task through an another app.
So I'd like to know how can I include my Gruntfile.js to this other app, and run the task.

For now this new app is really basic, juste a simple local web page using NodeJS, with a button that launch the task.

Gruntfile (I want to run the "archive" task)

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
require('time-grunt')(grunt);
require('jit-grunt')(grunt, {
    ngtemplates: "grunt-angular-templates"
});

var Generator = require("./generator.js")(grunt);
var generator = new Generator();
generator.printLogo();

// Build
grunt.registerTask("build", function (fileType) {
    //definition of build task
    grunt.task.run(tasks);
});

// Archive Task.
grunt.registerTask("archive", ["build", "compress", "clean:post-rsync"]);
};
```

Other file : (I tried a require, It seems to work, but I can't run the "archive" task of the Gruntfile.)

```
 var grunt = require('grunt');
 var gruntfile = require('./Gruntfile.js')(grunt);
 var app = express();

 app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('test.ejs');
 });

 app.post('/create', function(req, res){
     //run grunt task "archive" here

     //gruntfile.grunt.registerTask("archive", ["build"]);
     res.redirect('/');
 });

 app.listen(8080);
```

Do you have any idea how could I run the task in my gruntfile in this other file ?
(The function printLogo() is working so i'm sure the Gruntfile is include)

Thank you very much (I'm a beginner with Grunt so sorry if I miss something trivial)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just run a command from node. This way you don’t have to worry about dependencies and what not. You just spawn grunt, like you normally would, except programatically.

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

// This will run the 'archive' task of grunt
spawn('grunt', ['archive'], {
    cwd: 'path/to/grunt/project'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Grunt is a command line tool, the cleanest approach here would be to refactor your `Gruntfile` and extract your task's logics into a library.

Then from your `Gruntfile`'s task you can call that library, and from your `/create` route you can also call your library.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [grunt-hub](https://github.com/shama/grunt-hub) plugin:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  hub: {
    all: {
      src: ['../*/Gruntfile.js'],
      tasks: ['jshint', 'nodeunit'],
    },
  },
});
```